# mongodb $and Query not outputting desired result

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am running this query on my MongoDB Collection

```
{"$and":
    [
        {"$or": 
            [
                {"emailEngagement.dayEngagement": {"$elemMatch": { "day": 0, "sent": true }}},
                {"emailEngagement.dayEngagement": {"$elemMatch": { "day": 3, "sent": true }}}
            ]
        },
        {"metricsAllTime.accountCreated": {
            "$gte": "Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)",
            "$lt": "Mon Jun 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I run each query alone I get a result array of required fields. But when I combine them in $and I always get an empty array.

How should I write the query for it to return the accounts created between those dates and match the elements?

Comment: [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) needs an operator like `$or`, `$gte`, `$lte` etc, but in your 2nd query `"metricsAllTime.accountCreated"` its not an operator

Comment: @KunalMukherjee so i wrap the second query in `$or` ?

Comment: Yes wrap it in a `$or`, also I am doubtful `"metricsAllTime.accountCreated"` might be a date, but you are comparing strings, its recommended you parse it using [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) operator and then do a `$gte` or `$lte`

Comment: Turns out it was the `"metricsAllTime.accountCreated"` dates being strings instead of actual date objects. Changed them to date objects without wrapping the query in `$or` and It worked fine. Thanks @KunalMukherjee for the help!

Comment: Gotta be more careful man :)